# Access boolean in a Abstract class form fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, abstract-class

I'm having trouble with accessing a `boolean` of an abstract class from a fragment. Since a fragment cannot implement an abstract class how should I do it? Can someone help me? Below is my code.

```
public abstract class BaseChatViewModel extends BaseObservable {

protected User mUser;
protected UploadImage uploadImage;
protected String mLoggedUserEmail;

private MessageAdapterViewModelContract messageAdapterViewModelContract;

public BaseChatViewModel(User user, String loggedUserEmail) {
    mUser = user;
    mLoggedUserEmail = loggedUserEmail;
}
public BaseChatViewModel(UploadImage user, String loggedUserEmail) {
    uploadImage = user;
    mLoggedUserEmail = loggedUserEmail;
}

public BaseChatViewModel(UploadImage usehhr) {

    uploadImage =usehhr;

}

public String getName() {
    return !mUser.getEmail().equals(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_CHAT_GLOBAL)
            ? mUser.getName() : mUser.getName().replace("0", "");
}

public String getEmail() {
    return mUser.getEmail();
}


public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return mUser.getPhotoUrl();
}

public boolean isOnline() {
    return mUser.getEmail().equals(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_CHAT_GLOBAL) || mUser.isOnline();
}

public void onItemClick(View view) {
}


public boolean isSender() {
    return mLoggedUserEmail.equals(mUser.getEmail());

}



}

}
```

I need to access `isSender` from a fragment. How can I do this?

Comment: "Since a fragment cannot extend an abstract class" Where did you learn this?

Comment: The object of which class (inherited from BaseChatViewModel) are you using in your fragment?

Comment: did my answer solve your problem? even if it didn't, if you want to solve it, you should get back to the people who answer on what happened

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with "abstract classes". Rather it is only about creating objects of a class and making them available in the correct scope. You first need to obtain an object of type `BaseChatViewModel`. Then you can call any public methods on that object.

Answer (score 0):

> Since a fragment cannot extend an abstract class

is just **plain wrong**.

In all probability, you're facing this issue because your fragment to which you want to extend `BaseChatViewModel` is importing `android.app.Fragment` rather than `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.